# Delete SQL row from React front end

Tags: sql, reactjs, express, axios

I'm trying to delete a row in an SQL table from an input on a React front end.
Previously I has been successful in this but I've recently updated the columns in the table and haven't been able to recreate deleting from the table.
My best guess is that I havent passed the request correctly.
I the only data I can retrieve is the button does collect the username when pressed by the backend returns nothing and neither does my axios request.

Front end

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import Helmet from 'react-helmet';

export default function Database() {
    const [rows, setRows] = useState([]);
    const [username, setUsername] = useState('');

    useEffect(() => {
        axios.get('/users/get')
            .then(res => {
                setRows(res.data);
            }).catch(err => {
            console.log(err);
        });
    });

    //Delete from database api request
    const deleteRow = () => {
        axios.delete(`/users/delete/${username}`);
    };

    return (
        <>
            <Helmet>
                <title>Title | Database</title>
            </Helmet>
            
            <div className="pt-36 sm:pt-44 pb-20 md:pb-48 max-w-[1200px] mx-5 lg:mx-auto">
                {rows.map((row, index) => {
                    return (
                        <div key={index}>
                            <p>{row.first_name}</p>
                            <p>{row.last_name}</p>
                            <p>{row.email}</p>
                            <p>{row.username}</p>
                            <p>{row.password}</p>

                            <button onClick={() => {deleteRow(row.username)}}>Delete</button>
                        </div>
                    )
                })}
            </div>
        </>
    );
};
```

Back-end

```
const express = require('express');
const cors = require('cors');
const db = require('./config/db');

const app = express();
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 8080;

//Dependencies
app.use(express.json());
app.use(cors());

//#region Users table
    //Select all rows from table
    app.get('/users/get', (req, res) => {
        const selectAll = 'SELECT * FROM users'; //SQL query

        db.query(selectAll, (err, rows) => {
            if (err) throw err;
            res.send(rows);
        });
    });

    //Insert into database
    app.post('/users/insert', (req, res) => {
        const firstName = req.body.firstName;
        const lastName = req.body.lastName;
        const email = req.body.email;
        const username = req.body.username;
        const password = req.body.password;
        const insertRow = "INSERT INTO users (first_name, last_name, email, username, password) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";

        db.query(insertRow, [firstName, lastName, email, username, password], (err, rows) => { 
            if (err) throw err;
            console.log('inserted: ' + [firstName, lastName, email, username, password]); //Print row inserted
        });
    });

    //Delete from database
    app.delete('/users/delete/:username', (req, res) => {
        const username = req.params.username;
        const deleteRow = "DELETE FROM users WHERE username = ?";

        db.query(deleteRow, username, (err, rows) => {
            if (err) throw err;
            console.log('deleted: ' + username);
        });
    });

//Server port
app.listen(process.env.PORT || PORT, () => {
    console.log('Server started on port ' + PORT);
});
```

Comment: Is the endpoint getting called, if yes what is the API response?

Comment: The endpoint isnt getting called I get nothing from the back end or the axios request

Comment: Can you share the network calls? In the URL, you haven't added anything. Are you running your node server on the same port? You should be calling localhost:portnumber/users/delete/username

Comment: Ive defined the port at the top to be 8080 on localhost

Answer (score 0):

Not totally familiar with the syntax, just an idea -  maybe you need to pass the username in the function?

```
   const deleteRow = () => {
        axios.delete(`/users/delete/${username}`);
    };
```

Change to something like:

```
   const deleteRow = (username) => {
        axios.delete(`/users/delete/${username}`);
    };
```

Comment: I have dont the same function with a different table and didnt need to pass the username